# redux devtools config not working

Tags: redux, redux-devtools-extension

I am trying to configure my app to use the redux-devtools
but it's somehow not working.

here was my config before using redux-devtools

```
var persistedState = loadState();

var createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk,loadingBarMiddleware(),errorBarMiddleware()),reduxReset())(createStore);

export var store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers,persistedState);
```

Here's what i did to use redux-devtools

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
var createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk,loadingBarMiddleware(),errorBarMiddleware()),reduxReset())(createStore);

const store = createStore(reducers, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(
  createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers,persistedState)
));
```

but with this I am getting the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: reducer is not a function
```

So, where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured out the problem and now it's working for me.

all, I had to do was to add the redux devtools code to my previous code like this.
seems like I was making it more complicated than it should have been.

anyways, the working code is

```
var persistedState = loadState();

var createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk,loadingBarMiddleware(),errorBarMiddleware()),reduxReset())(createStore);

export var store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers,persistedState,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
```

it was as simple as that.